# Iterating over variable with jQuery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I set this variable at the top of my page `setVars = {"n":"2","m":"1","degree":"3","p":"2"}`

I want to iterate over each of the elements in setVars but jquery's each() function isn't working.

Here's what I have -

```
$(setVars).each(function(key, value) {
  elementId = '#' + key+ '-wrapper';
}
```

But `key` is set to 0 here on the first iteration and `value` is set to the full setVars object here for some reason. It doesn't make it to a second iteration, it breaks when I step through it and try to go to the second iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like that I belive according to this http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

```
$.each(setVars, function(key, value) {
  elementId = '#' + key+ '-wrapper';
});
```

setVars is not a collection of DOM elements, it is an object

Answer (score 1):

You are using [`.each()` that's meant for iterating through jQuery objects](http://api.jquery.com/each/) instead of [`$.each()` that's meant for iterating through objects and arrays](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/). Try this:

```
$.each( setVars, function(key, value) {
  elementId = '#' + key+ '-wrapper';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need JQuery for this.  Also I could be wrong but you don't want the quotes around the name of the object properties you never see that:

```
setVars = {n:"2",m:"1",degree:"3",p:"2"}
```

And

```
for(i in setVars){
   console.log("key: ",i," value: ", setVars[i]); // demonstration of how to access key and value
   elementId = '#' + i + '-wrapper';
}
```

Comment: The setVars variable comes from a PHP script where I encoded a PHP array.